# Pass data from AuthorizationHandler to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a custom `AuthorizationHandler` setup that checks my db for an apikey.  It works fine, but I want to be able to return data from it back to the controller.  The apikey has properties that I want to be able to use in the controller, so I want the apikey object that's being used in the handler passed back to the controller.

Apikey:

```
public class ApiKey
{
    public string apikeyid { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public string apikey { get; set; }
    public bool isactive { get; set;}
    public bool ispaid { get; set; }
    public bool ismod { get; set; }
    public bool isadmin { get; set; }
}
```

Controller decorator:

`[Authorize(Policy = "ApiKey")]`

Handler:

```
public class ApiKeyRequirementHandler : 
AuthorizationHandler<ApiKeyRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _appContext;
    private readonly ILogger<ApiKeyRequirementHandler> _logger;
    public ApiKeyRequirementHandler(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, ApplicationDbContext appContext, ILogger<ApiKeyRequirementHandler> logger)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        _appContext = appContext;
        _logger = logger;
    }
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ApiKeyRequirement requirement)
{
    string rawAuthHeader = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    //_logger.LogDebug(rawAuthHeader);
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawAuthHeader))
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    string[] headers = rawAuthHeader.Split(",");
    Dictionary<string, string> authHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string sentApiKey = "";

    foreach(string header in headers)
    {
        if(header.Contains("APIKEY"))
        {
            string[] splitHeader = header.Split(" ");
            authHeaders.Add(splitHeader[0], splitHeader[1]);   
            sentApiKey = authHeaders["APIKEY"];             
        }
    }

    var searchApiKeys = _appContext.apikey.AsQueryable().Where(a => a.apikey == sentApiKey);

    foreach(ApiKey foundKey in searchApiKeys)
    {
        if(foundKey.apikey == sentApiKey && foundKey.isactive)
        {
            //can I do something here to pass searchApiKey back?
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
}
```

Comment: you could add it to the HttpContext.Items collection in the handler and retrieve it from there in the controller